# How to auto update Gmail credentials after expiring

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth

I am using Gmail Java API,
API is working fine and when we grant google account access credentials are storing locally, but after 60 minutes credentials are expiring, it is not automatically updating credentials.When debugging with my code it is stopped at

> Credential credential = app.authorize("user");

How to handle after expiring credentials, it is again working only after calling oauth2 authentication.is it possible to auto-refresh this functionality
This is my code block

```
/**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
                Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        User user =  (User) session.getAttribute("USER");
        java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
                //System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/"+user.getUserAccountId()+"/gmail-java-quickstart");
                Common.commonPath+File.separator+"client_secrets"+File.separator+user.getUserAccountId()+"/gmail-java-quickstart");
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();
        System.out.println("*************getApprovalPrompt:"+flow.getApprovalPrompt());
        AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp app = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()){
            protected void onAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl) throws java.io.IOException {
                //System.out.println("authorizationUrl:"+authorizationUrl);
            }
        };
        Credential credential = app.authorize("user");
        //System.out.println("*************AUTH_KKEY:"+credential.getAccessToken());
        //System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Gmail client service.
     * @return an authorized Gmail client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Gmail getGmailService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public List<Message> listMessagesWithLabels(List<String> labelIds,StringBuilder paginationtokenBuilder,Long maxResults) throws IOException {
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        try {
            Gmail service = getGmailService();
            // some logic bla bla
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return messages;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is a little late but do you run this code more than one e-mail address for the same user account at the same computer? Your code seems it should work fine. I can only think of that refresh token is not working because you hard coded `userId` which is `"user"`. It might be overwriting credentials for different users with the same  `userId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay, I faced the same problem but no luck with API. I got some work around for the issue, check out if it helps.

When the token expires, the API gives exception (or timeout in some cases). Here the token could be refreshed manually (may be with a catch block). the subsequent request would continue with the updated token which is refreshed by previous request. Code snippet below.

Incase of Exception:

```
try {
    response1 = Quickstart.getGmailService().users().messages().list(userId).setLabelIds(labelIds).execute();       
    return response1.getResultSizeEstimate();
} catch (com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH+File.separator+"client_secrets"));
    response.sendRedirect("/dashboard"); // redirect to your oauth request URI
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Incase of timeout (UI):

```
$.ajax({
    url:"listGmailLabels", // Request that is hitting Gmail API
    type:"POST",
    success:function(data){
        // Success logic goes here
    },
    complete:function(event){
        if(event.status == 504){
            alert('Token expired! Getting a new refresh token.');
            $.ajax({
                url:"clearClientSecret", // service call to cleanup the expired token
                success:function(){
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            })
        }
    }
 });
```

Service for cleaning up the expired token:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/clearClientSecret",method= {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
    public void clearClientSecret(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            String path=CLIENT_SECRET_PATH+File.separator+"client_secrets";
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(path));
            response.sendRedirect("/dashboard");// redirect to your oauth request URI
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I know it might not be a proper solution but this is what I tried as a work around, so let all of us know if there is anything could make it better.